# SSLRequire - file function

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, files, mod-ssl

I'm having trouble with Apache 2.2 and the small documentation that I can find for the **file** function of SSLRequire. I'm trying to check the email property of the client certificate in a request using **SSLRequire**.

The following option in httpd.conf file works well:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} in { "mail@example.com" }
```

but as can I read in the documentation you can use a list of values for filter.

Quoting from the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire):

> `file`(filename)-  This function takes one string argument and expands to the contents of the file. This is especially useful for
>   matching this contents against a regular expression, etc.

So, following the documentation I put the following in the httpd.conf file:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} in { file("/etc/httpd/mail-list") }
```

The file mail-list contains only one line with the content `mail@example.com` (trying to simulate the option that works without `file`).

But when I try to access to my  HTTPS server I see the following in the logs:

```
Failed expression: %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} in { file("/etc/httpd/mail-list") }
```

This message normally appears when the pattern can't be applied.  Can someone help me here, how can I use this functionality?

Comment: The expression you say works has a `#` in front of it: `#SSLRequire`, which makes it a comment.  Are you sure it works?  Is the `#` really there in your config?

Comment: Is /etc/httpd/mail-list readable by the Apache user (apache or www-data)?

Comment: The line is not commented on my tests, of course.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this old thread](http://marc.info/?l=apache-modssl&m=93323761001866&w=2) on the apache-modssl mailing list, `file()` reads the contents of the file into a single string, and so special characters (such as newlines) in the referenced file may break the `SSLRequire` syntax.

Given that this was posted by the original author of `mod_ssl`, I'd trust this theory to be spot on.

Try with the following contents in `/etc/httpd/mail-list`:

```
"mail@example.com","mail@example.org","mail2@example.org"
```

with no trailing newline

Comment: I've tested it and it doesn't work...my apache version is 2.2.15. Anything more that I have to take into account?. Thanks!

Comment: @Jos3k4 Not AFAIK. Still the same error ("Failed expression:")?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

file() does read the contents of the file into a single string (as M. Jessen noted). However, that doesn't mean that you can use apache expression syntax inside this file. You will need to use a regular expression to search inside the string, as apache doesn't seem to be able to split a string based on a delimiter.

As a workaround you can use [AuthBasicFake](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicfake) and use the variable in question as the basic auth username together with a normal basic auth provider.